# WinBUGS error with zero values in binomial distribution: value of order of binomial <expr> must be greater than zero

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, bugs

It seems that WinBUGS has problems **if it has only zero draws from one binomial distribution**:

**1. case - simple model**

```
for (i in 1:sites) {
    N[i] ~ dpois(lambda)
    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i, j] ~ dbin(p, N[i])
    }
}
```

If all values `y[i,]` are zero, then the following error message appears:

> **value of order of binomial y[53,1] must be greater than zero**

**EDIT:** note that `N[i]` was not zero in generated data upon failure.

**2. case - advanced removal model**

```
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M[i] ~ dpois(lambda)    

    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i, j, 1] ~ dbin(p, M[i])

        after_removal[i, j] <- M[i] - y[i, j, 1]
        y[i, j, 2] ~ dbin(p, after_removal[i, j])
    }
}
```

Here it seems that if some `y[i, j, 2]` is zero then the error message (same as in case 1) appears!

Note that in this case, I found a workaround: I reparametrized the model to different one which **I hope** is equivalent:

```
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M[i] ~ dpois(lambda)    

    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i, j, 1] ~ dbin(p, M[i])
        obs[i, j] <- y[i, j, 1] + y[i, j, 2]
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p_komb, M[i])
    }
}

p_komb <- p + (1 - p) * p
```

... anyway an explanation, clean solution and solution for case 1 wanted:

### Why this happens? Is it a WinBUGS bug? How can it be overriden?

I have WinBUGS 1.4.3 (August 2007) with immortality patch installed.
Below is complete **reproducible code for R and package R2WinBUGS (with data generation)**:

**1. case**

```
require(vcd)

sites <- 120 # 60

mean_N <- 16

N <- rpois(sites, mean_N) 


p <- 0.4

sample <- 3 # 3

y = matrix(nrow = sites, ncol = sample)
for (i in 1:sites) {
    y[i,] = rbinom(sample, N[i], p)
}
y[20,] = 0

sink("tmp_bugs/model.txt")
cat("

model {

# likelihood
for (i in 1:sites) {
    N[i] ~ dpois(lambda)
    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i, j] ~ dbin(p, N[i])
    }
}

# derived parameters
Ntot <- sum(N[])

# priors

p <- 1/(1+exp(-logit_p))
tau <- 1/(4 * 4)
logit_p ~ dnorm(0, tau)

lambda ~ dunif(0, 100)

}


")
sink()

win.data = list(y = y, sample = sample, sites = sites)
#win.data = list(y = y)

#inits = function () { list(N = apply(y, 1, max), p = mean(apply(y, 1, mean)/apply(y, 1, max))) }
inits = function () { list(N = apply(y, 1, max), logit_p = rnorm(1, 0, 4)) }


params = c("N", "p", "Ntot", "lambda")

ni <- 500
nt <- 12
nb <- 200
nc <- 3


out <- bugs(win.data, inits, params, "model.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt, bugs.directory = bugs.dir, 
    working.directory = paste(getwd(), "/tmp_bugs/", sep = ""),
    debug = TRUE
)

print(out, dig = 3)

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
hist(out$sims.list$p, breaks = 100)
abline(v = out$mean$p, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = p, col = "green", lwd = 2)
#lines(quantile(out$sims.list$p, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(sum(par("usr")[3:4]*c(0.9,0.1)), 2), lwd = 2)
lines(quantile(out$sims.list$p, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(par("usr")[3], 2), lwd = 4)
legend("topleft", c("estimated", "real", "95% cred. int."), col = c("red", "green", "black"), lty = 1, box.lty = 0, cex = 0.7)

#hist(mean(y) / out$sims.list$p, breaks = 1000, xlim = c(0, 50))

hist(out$sims.list$Ntot, breaks = 100)
abline(v = out$mean$Ntot, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = sum(N), col = "green", lwd = 2)
#lines(quantile(out$sims.list$Ntot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(sum(par("usr")[3:4]*c(0.9,0.1)), 2), lwd = 2)
lines(quantile(out$sims.list$Ntot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(par("usr")[3], 2), lwd = 4)
legend("topright", c("estimated total N", "real total N", "95% credible int."), col = c("red", "green", "black"), lty = 1, box.lty = 0, cex = 0.7)
```

**2. case**

(one of the `y[i, j, 2]` will likely be zero; if not, it can be assigned directly)

```
require(vcd)

sites <- 120 # 60

mean_M <- 16

M <- rpois(sites, mean_M) 

p <- 0.4 #0.64

sample <- 2 # 3

y = rep(NA, sites * sample * 2)
dim(y) = c(sites, sample, 2)

for (i in 1:sites) {
#   obs[i,] = rbinom(sample, M[i], p)
    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i,j,1] = rbinom(1, M[i], p)
        y[i,j,2] = rbinom(1, M[i] - y[i,j,1], p)
    }
}

y_sample_total = apply(y, c(1, 2), sum)
obs = y_sample_total

############################################

sink("tmp_bugs/model.txt")
cat("

model {

# likelihood
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M[i] ~ dpois(lambda)    

    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i, j, 1] ~ dbin(p, M[i])

        after_removal[i, j] <- M[i] - y[i, j, 1]
        y[i, j, 2] ~ dbin(p, after_removal[i, j]) 
    }
}

# derived parameters
Mtot <- sum(M[])

# priors

tau <- 1/(4 * 4)

p <- 1/(1+exp(-logit_p))
logit_p ~ dnorm(0, tau)

lambda ~ dunif(0, 100)

}
")
sink()


win.data = list(y = y, 
    #obs = y_sample_total, 
    sample = sample, sites = sites)

inits = function () { list(
    M = apply(y_sample_total, 1, max), 
    logit_p = rnorm(1, 0, 4)
) }

#params = c("M", "M2", "p", "p2", "Mtot", "M2tot", "lambda", "lambda2")
params = c("M", "p", "Mtot", "lambda")

ni <- 2500
nt <- 16
nb <- 1000
nc <- 3

date()
out <- bugs(win.data, inits, params, "model.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt, bugs.directory = "C:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/", 
    working.directory = paste(getwd(), "/tmp_bugs/", sep = ""),
    debug = TRUE
)
date()



#############################

print(out, dig = 3)

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

hist(out$sims.list$p, breaks = 100)
abline(v = out$mean$p, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = p, col = "green", lwd = 2)
#lines(quantile(out$sims.list$p, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(sum(par("usr")[3:4]*c(0.9,0.1)), 2), lwd = 2)
lines(quantile(out$sims.list$p, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(par("usr")[3], 2), lwd = 4)
legend("topleft", c("estimated", "real", "95% cred. int."), col = c("red", "green", "black"), lty = 1, box.lty = 0, cex = 0.7)

#hist(mean(y) / out$sims.list$p, breaks = 1000, xlim = c(0, 50))

hist(out$sims.list$Mtot, breaks = 100)
abline(v = out$mean$Mtot, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = sum(M), col = "green", lwd = 2)
#lines(quantile(out$sims.list$Mtot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(sum(par("usr")[3:4]*c(0.9,0.1)), 2), lwd = 2)
lines(quantile(out$sims.list$Mtot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(par("usr")[3], 2), lwd = 4)
legend("topright", c("estimated total M", "real total M", "95% credible int."), col = c("red", "green", "black"), lty = 1, box.lty = 0, cex = 0.7)


hist(out$sims.list$lambda)
```

Comment: For your 1st case, the problem is when N[i]=0 !

Comment: No, the N[i] in generated data can be non-zero (note that WinBUGS doesn't see generated N vector). The problem occurs (in the 1st case), when `y[i, j]` are zero for all `j` for given `i`. Also please note that this should be comment, not an answer.

Comment: The probability for a N[i] to be zero is positive, it is exactly $e^{-\lambda}$. So the comment from @Stéphane Laurent is valid.

Comment: My answer has been converted to a comment because it is too short... but there's nothing more to say !!!

Comment: @teucer, the Stephane's comment is not valid - it states that the behaviour is due to `N[i]` in generated data being zero, but `N[i]` in the generated data was not zero upon failure.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, as I said, the `N[i]` I generated in R script was not zero in my case. So your answer could not be considered an answer, rather a comment. To downvoter: please explain the downvote, don't donwvote just because you don't understand the problem or my clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Tomas, although I did not downvote this question, I can see why it is collecting downvotes: the question itself is nicely formulated in the first dozen lines preceding the "Edit" but the rest of the stuff is just distracting noise.  Also, you seem not to be taking the comments here seriously: that tends to cause people to downvote even when they have not participated in the commenting.

Comment: @Tomas, the N[i] you generated are just initial values, and the crash occurs when a posterior simulation of N[i] is zero

Comment: @Stéphane, yes, you and whuber are right! I did not understood what you meant because `N[i]` is simulated by MCMC, not giveen by me... but after reading whubers answer I realized that I forgot to look at the initial value, which was zero! Thanks, now I see what you meant! But anyway, I feel that `N[i] = 0` is absolutely valid in my case and should be allowed. It is a total number of animals at site `i`, and `y[i, j]` is number of animals actually seen during visit `j`. So `N[i] = 0` is perfectly valid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@Stephane appears to be correct:**

> For your 1st case, the problem is when N[i]=0 !

This problem is easy to reproduce and it's straightforward to test his conclusion.  E.g., compile this model

```
model {
    for (i in 1:sites) {
        N[i] ~ dpois(lambda)
        for (j in 1:sample) {
            y[i, j] ~ dbin(p, N[i])
        }
    }
}
```

with a simple set of data such as

```
list(
  y = structure(
    .Data = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    .Dim = c(4,2)
  ),
  lambda = 1,
  sites = 4, sample = 2, p = 0.5
)
```

(Note that all data values are zero.)  When you try to generate initial values for the chains, your error is raised:

> value of order of binomial y[1,1] must be greater than zero

Now change lambda from a small value to a large one (for which N[i]==0 will essentially never happen):

```
...
lambda = 100,
...
```

The model runs fine.

You can also vary the data `c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` to confirm that their values do not affect the error.  *Ergo*, the error *must* be due to either to an invalid value of N[i] or p.  Clearly p (= 0.5) is valid, QED.

Comment: Very nice answer, whuber.

Comment: However I am not sure to agree with your last remark: the posterior of N[i] is automatically distributed on values greater than every y[i,j], hence there's nothing to specify to (Win)BUGS.

Comment: whuber, thanks! I was confused by comments of others as I thought I'm not responsible for `N[i]` - the sampler is - but after reading your answer I realized that I forgot to look at the initial value of `N[i]`, which I've set to zero.

Comment: But anyway, I feel that `N[i] = 0` is absolutely valid in my case and should be allowed in `dbin`! It is a total number of animals at site `i`, and `y[i, j]` is number of animals actually seen during visit `j`. So `N[i] = 0` is perfectly valid for my binomial distribution. So it should be somehow possible to treat this in WinBUGS also..

Comment: That's a great point, Tomas: N[i]==0 corresponds to a certainty that the outcome will be 0.  Consider streamlining your question (in another edit) to focus on this issue: namely, how can one persuade BUGS to accept this degenerate case?

Comment: Thanks whuber for support! Maybe this would be worth of a separate question. The original question *why* I got the error is now answered, thanks!